# ntpd -gq hangs and time is not updated

Tags: ntp, timekeeping

In attempts to synchronize time, following the advice to run `$ sudo ntpd -qg`. This does not terminate on its own, and the time is not updated.

How to debug this problem?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start
[ ok ] Starting ntp (via systemctl): ntp.service.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ntpq -pn
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 85.199.214.101  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 217.114.59.66   .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 217.114.59.3    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 213.251.53.217  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Here's what `ntpq` sees. I don't like this `.INIT.`.

Testing UDP connectivity to one of those listed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nc -v -u -z -w 3 0.pool.ntp.org 123
Connection to 0.pool.ntp.org 123 port [udp/ntp] succeeded!
```

Comment: What changes have you made that necessitated starting ntpd manually? By default, the Pi will connect automatically and sync the time. Please also post your ntpd.conf file. How is the Pi connected to the internet? What model Pi are you using?

Comment: I did not start it manually. I stopped it to sync the time manually with `ntpd -qg`. `ntpd.conf` is stock. Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Recent Raspbian *may* be using `timesyncd` instead of ntpd.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 8, like many recent releases of major Linux distributions, now uses systemd to manage the daemons and servers, so you want to use `systemctl status ntp` to see whether it's currently running and the last few log messages and `start`, `stop` and `restart` in place of `status` above to perform those actions.

Keep in mind that `ntpd` can take several minutes to start synchronizing time after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when connecting the Pi to my Uni wired network. To solve I had to ask the IT guys to provide me the ntp pool server they use, edit the `ntp.config` file and the problem was solved. If you are connecting to a non-domestic network, that might be the source of the problem.