# pi zero running raspbian has UTC time 4 hours off

Tags: ntp

Ok, I have this raspberry pi zero that's been running for most of a year now and I noticed a few weeks ago that the time was off by several hours. I did some digging and it just plain thinks that UTC time is 4 hours before what it should be.

I poke around the internets, and tried the items [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/65815/ntpd-gq-hangs-and-time-is-not-updated) to no avail. I found [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59893) and my `ntp.conf` file is exactly the same (I ran diff on them to verify). I haven't tried setting the time explicitly with `ntp -s...` because I was under the impression that's what ntp is for?

I've set the timezone using the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` command (and `sudo raspi-config` but those seem to get to the same menu with the same options). This results in the timezone being ok, but UTC is still off.

```
pi@raintree:~ $ date
Mon Sep 17 04:13:52 PDT 2018
pi@raintree:~ $ 
pi@raintree:~ $ date -u
Mon Sep 17 11:13:58 UTC 2018
```

Right now, that should show `Mon Sep 17 15:13:58 UTC 2018`. **EDIT** I am referencing https://time.is/UTC. Screen shot [here](https://time.is/UTC).

ntpq seems to be ok.

```
pi@raintree:~ $ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 li290-38.member .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 PBX.cytranet.ne .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 ns1.backplanedn .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 195.21.152.161  .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Any ideas on where else to look?

Misc info:

```
pi@raintree:~ $ uname -a
Linux raintree 4.9.35+ #1014 Fri Jun 30 14:34:49 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@raintree:~ $ 
pi@raintree:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
```

Comment: if your local time at the moment was 04:13, then the UTC time is correct as PDT equals UTC-7.

Comment: Understood, which is why I posted the time it should say `Mon Sep 17 15:13:58 UTC 2018`. That is the "current" (at the time of the post) time in UTC. So it is 4 hours off.

Comment: What was your LOCAL time back then and what was your source for UTC?

Comment: Do you have another system that you can check UTC?

Comment: I used [https://time.is/UTC](https://time.is/UTC). I posted a [screen shot here](https://imgur.com/2JklRpi)

Comment: So in fact also your whole system time was off by 4h and not the displayed UTC relatively to your local time. The local time is also off by that amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ntp can't correct such a lapse.  On boot, I run ntpdate before starting ntp, ntpdate can handle any correction.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I installed ntpdate, but when I ran it, I got `19 Sep 19:35:29 ntpdate[2676]: no servers can be used, exiting`, I re-ran `raspi-config` and selected my timezone and now seem to be in a good place. I'm guessing having ntpdate allowed the `raspi-config` to properly set the date.

Comment: Oh, how are you starting ntpdate each boot?

Comment: I "tweaked" /etc/init.d/ntp, first thing in the start function is now ntpdate.

Answer (score 0):

If the time on your Raspberry is off by hours with 0 minute, then I suspect it is a problem with your timezone setting. You already said that you had reconfigured your Rpi with a correct timezone using either *dpkg-reconfigure tzdata* and/or *raspi-config*. However, make sure the changes to just made did get updated in the /etc/timezone file.

Comment: Huh, my `/etc/timezone` file was not updated. I installed ntpdate per Gerard's post and it seems to have been updated after that. :shrug: